# Can I host an xpi on a secure server that requires login?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I would like to host my Firefox extension on my company's wiki, which is accessed over HTTPS and requires a username/password to access. Can I host my extension there? I can't seem to find anything over at the Mozilla documentation that supports this.

I'm building my xpi with the following:

`cfx xpi --update-link https://wiki.example.com/download/attachments/12132392/my-addon.xpi --update-url https://wiki.example.com/download/attachments/12132392/my-addon.update.rdf`

Additional details:

- Firefox 34
- addon-sdk-1.17

Comment: You could always try it. You might get a popup for the Basic Authentication (?) or if your employees are already logged into the wiki at the time of the update it might just work.

Comment: Okay, for anyone else reading this, it seems to work.

Comment: Nice, then you could add it as an answer and immediately approve it, that way others don't think this is still unsolved. :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Confirming that this does in fact work. You can hose your xpi on a secure server location if you'd like.